# Endereço absoluto (incluindo o script) em PHP

Tags: php

Considere o seguinte endereço html:

```
http://exemplo.com/1/2/3/teste.php
```

Queria indicar na variável `$ender` o endereço absoluto dos meus scripts (incluindo-os) para que fossem achados independente da mudança de endereço (de estar na raiz ou subdiretório). Tentei isso `"http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"` para tentar pelo menos substituir isso: (`http://exemplo.com/1/2/3/`). Não funcionou. O que queria evitar a literalidade de tudo (`http://exemplo.com/1/2/3/teste.php`). Só tive algum sucesso parcial com http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST], mas só substitui o endereço base.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']$SERVER['REQUEST_URI']/;
$id   = $_GET['id'];
if ($id == 1) {
```

Comment: Você está tentando interpolar isso direto numa string, é isso? `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` traz tudo que vier depois do domínio (host), não é isso que você precisa?

Comment: Eu tentei isso mas não funcionou (se a forma que eu descrevi acima estiver correta). tb não consegui com $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]

Comment: Só que não dá pra entender onde está o problema. Mostre um pedaço do seu código real, do jeito que está na pergunta não sabemos direito o que você está fazendo

Comment: @bfavaretto, inclui a parte do código de como coloquei o endereço.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que você tem um erro de sintaxe aí. Tente assim:

```
$protocolo = empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http://': 'https://';
$url = $protocolo . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $url;
```

Comment: Não funcionou a contento. Mesmo só considerando essa parte: http://exemplo.com/1/2/3/ só resolve parcialmente.